# Android Studio - Logcat does not take me to the line of code where Exception occured

Tags: android, logcat

hi I am reading Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide.

In chapter 4, it says if I do this in Logcat :  "Double-click this line, and Eclipse will take you to that line in your source code."

The problem is I'm using Android Studio and when I double click on that line or any other line it does not take me to the line of code in Android Studio. Is this how is it suppose to be working? If so how do I get to the line of code that caused the exception?

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: in the logcat you get your `Activity/Fragment` highlighted with line number in blue color, if you click it you will be navigated to that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio will navigate to the line where the exception occurred by double clicking on the logcat. I think your viewing logcat from "Android Device Monitor". If so close it and you will get the default logcat at the bottom of the android studio window.

Comment: yes Im viewing logcat from ADM. will try your suggestions when I get home later. thnx